# Why doesnt the '\b' work after using a for-loop in java?

Tags: java

```
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.print("B x ");
    }
    System.out.print("\b\b");
```

I want to get the answer as `B x B x B x B x B`,  but the `\b\b` doesn't work so that the answer becomes `B x B x B x B x B x`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's Working Fine , Run it again Using some ide like netbeans or Eclipse]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    System.out.print("B x ");
}
System.out.print("\b\b");
}
```

run:
B x B x B x B x B 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I used geany to compile and run that java program, but in it the \b\b did not work, it works fine in netbeans. Can i know the reason why that happens?

Answer (score 3):

`\b` will move the cursor backwards, but it's not like the backspace key; it doesn't erase characters. Print a space to hide the last `x`.

```
System.out.print("\b\b ");
```

Comment: Is it after an update? or was it like that from the beginning

Comment: It is like that from the beginning but some compiler optimisatons may show some difference among various compilers. For oracle refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html